# Setting “Allow Fill-In” on taxonomy fields with PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

When i try to set **FillInChoice="TRUE"** on the Taxonomy fields using **Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate** on my Sharepoint Online Library, the value is not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below pnp script to set Allow 'Fill-in' choices:

```
set-PnPField -List "TestLibrary" -Identity "Test" -Values @{Open=$true;CreateValuesInEditForm=$true}
```

Comment: Thank you for the script Michael. Any idea why it does not work when using the FillInChoice property with Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate?  Is it a limitation?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe there's no such  FillInChoice property with Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this with the following line:

```
Set-PnPField -List "Listname" -Identity "FieldInternalName" -Values @{FillInChoice = $true }
```